# How to Get url encoded value using escape() function

Tags: javascript

i have this string  `<%=Master.UserNTGroup %> = "#Marketing"`

```
var xyz= escape(<%=Master.UserNTGroup %>)
```

but i am not able to get that value , i am getting "".

Comment: Does Master.UserNTGroup actually include quotes? If not `escape("<%=Master.UserNTGroup %>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot put argument string in quotes, and as said on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) escape() function is deprecated, use encodeURI(uri) instead escape(uri);

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes:

```
var xyz= escape("<%=Master.UserNTGroup %>");
                ^                        ^
```

> **Note:** The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead.